# jQuery toggleClass() method not applying to JSON generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a nice list of CSS generated cards. They contain icons and text and have a nice animation to expand once you tap on them, to reveal more icons and options. I hard coded the list and got it looking and behaving exactly the way I wanted.

Now, I have some JSON data on a database and I want to use that data to populate the list dynamically.

**Problem**: It works great, except the CSS animations, which are triggered by jQuery toggleClass() no longer apply.

How can I fix this?  Here's my code.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customFitStyling.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3c_v4.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/customFitFunctions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--APPEND CARDS-->
    <ul id="cardList" class="cards">

    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
    // Sync with Firebase in real time.
    dbRef.on("value", snap =>
    {
      var workouts = snap.val();

      for (var i = 0, len = workouts.length; i < len; i++) // Populate list.
      {
        $("#cardList").append("<li><div class='card transform'>\n\
        <div class='cardInfo'><h3>" + workouts[i].title + "</h3><p>10 min.</p><a class='startIt' href='timer.html'>\n\
        <img src='images/playIcon.png' width='70' alt='' /></a><div class='infoIcons'>\n\
        <img src='images/thorso.png' width='48' alt='' /><img src='images/legs.png' width='28' alt='' />\n\
        <img src='images/cardio.png' width='48' alt='' /></div><div class='timeIcon'>\n\
        <img src='images/tenMinutes.png' width='66' alt='' /></div></div>\n\
        <div class='disappear'><div class='playIt'><a class='playButton' href='timer.html'>\n\
        <img src='images/playButtonUp.png' width='100' alt='' /><img src='images/playButtonDown.png' width='95' alt='' /></a>\n\
        </div><div class='deleteIt'><a class='deleteButton' href='#'>\n\
        <img src='images/thrashButtonUp.png' width='60' alt='' />\n\
        <img src='images/thrashButtonDown.png' width='55' alt='' /></a></div><div class='modifyIt'>\n\
        <a class='modifyButton' href='#'><img src='images/cogButtonUp.png' width='100' alt=''/>\n\
        <img src='images/cogButtonDown.png' width='95' alt='' /></a></div></div></div></li>");
      }
    });
```

jQuery:

```
  // Triggers CSS animation for cards.
  $(".card").click(function()
  {
    $(this).toggleClass("transformActive");
    $(".disappear", this).toggleClass("appear");
  });
```

CSS:

```
/**
* ROUTINE CARDS SECTION
*
*/
/* Style cards and content */
.cards
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cards li
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.card
{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  left: -6%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #686868;
}

.transform
{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.transformActive
{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

/* CARD CONTENT SECTION */
.cardInfo
{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 130px;
  text-align: left;
}

.cardInfo h3
{
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.cardInfo p
{
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  top: -40px;
}

.startIt
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.timeIcon
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 78%;
}

.infoIcons
{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: -20px;
  width: 52%;
  height: 100px;
}

.infoIcons img
{
  margin-left: 6px;
}

#holder
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

/* CARD ANIMATION */
.disappear
{
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 8%;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}

.appear
{
  -webkit-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  -o-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  -ms-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes appearFade
{
  0%
  {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%
  {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* CARD OPTIONS ICONS */
.playIt
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.playButton img:last-child
{
  display: none;
}

.playButton:hover img:first-child
{
  display: none;
}

.playButton:hover img:last-child
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
}

.deleteIt
{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 25px;
}

.deleteButton img:last-child
{
  display: none;
}

.deleteButton:hover img:first-child
{
  display: none;
}

.deleteButton:hover img:last-child
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}

.modifyIt
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.modifyButton img:last-child
{
  display: none;
}

.modifyButton:hover img:first-child
{
  display: none;
}

.modifyButton:hover img:last-child
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `.card` items are being added after your click listener is attached it won't work. The element needs to be there at the time you bind the listener. You should use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Attach the click listener to your container element, and then use `event.target` as the element you clicked on:

```
$('#cardList').on('click', '.card', (event) => {
  // $(event.target) is the element you clicked
  $(event.target).toggleClass('transformActive');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are adding the click handler before you are adding the elements, so only the initial elements have that click event on them. Instead you can add the click handler to the `body` but filter it.

```
$('body').on('click', '.card', function(){ ... }
```

This way the click event is on the entire document, but the function will not fire unless you clicked a card.

Answer (score 0):

So, I suspect that the issue is not the toggleClass, but rather the click handler. For jQuery to act on a DOM element, that element has to be present at the time the site completes initial loading.

If you are populating the content after load using JSON, you wont be able to act on the DOM elements the content resides in.

All of your initial classes are being added in the JSON content - so none of them exist at load - jQuery knows nothing about their existence.

Your click targets must be present on load to resolve your issue. So, dont put DOM elements in your JSON. Have them already populated, and feed the JSON data into the existing elements. OR - tie your click events to a DOM element higher up that exists on load. Then the dynamic elements will be able to bubble up and jQuery will have something to watch
.